# Ethernet port working in Kali, but not in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, ethernet, lan

I recently tried to connect my Raspberry Pi to my Dell Inspiron n5010 through the Ethernet port. To my shock, my laptop did not detect the network (didn't show the limited network icon), but the lights on the Ethernet port of the Pi were lit up.

After analysis I came to know that my adapter, even after having all the drivers installed was not listed in the Device manager. I even cannot see the Local Area Network or Ethernet connection in my Network connections. I popped open my laptop to make sure the card was properly connected and it was. I then booted up into Kali and tried connecting the Raspberry Pi again, and this time it worked. Kali detected that a device had been connected over the Ethernet port.

My first guess were drivers, which I immediately updated from Realtek but nothing happened. I tried deleting the Network adapters in Device manager but they didn't get deleted. (when I press the delete option nothing happens).I tried reinstalling the chipset and the Ethernet drivers, but no good. The port was working just fine when I used it a few day back while playing CoD with my friend, our computers connected directly through Ethernet ports.

This is how my Device Manager looks like- [Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLwYk.jpg). The Broadcom adapter in the image is the WiFi adapter. My Ethernet adapter is Realtek RTL8103T.

This is how my Network Connections look- [Network connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vry7Y.jpg)

I have no idea left except to do a fresh install of Windows, which I want to avoid, so if there's any way to fix this, please let me know...
Thanks.

EDIT : I reinstalled windows and the port seems to work now. I was able to connect my netbook running Kali over Ethernet to my laptop. The Ethernet connection only appears in the Network connections when the LAN is connected. Same for the Device manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The reinstall worked. I formatted my C: Drive (System Drive), then I installed the drivers in this order-

1. Chipset Driver
2. Display Driver
3. WLAN/LAN (Ethernet Drivers)
4. Others (Touchpad, audio etc. I don't really install these)

My PC can now detect the Raspberry Pi over LAN...